# What's the benefit of storing state in ViewModel (from Android Architecture Components) rather the Application class or a Singleton?

Tags: android

Storing state inside the Application class or a singleton has the added benefit of sharing across activities too (is there a simple way to share one ViewModel across two activities I'm unaware of?)

Also a singleton can be as android free as a ViewModel can be, so testing locally (without an android device or emulator) shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Storing state inside the Application class or a singleton has the added benefit of sharing across activities too

It is also a memory leak. Use that for things that are truly process-wide, and make sure that you are taking steps to cap the memory use (e.g., limit the size of any caches that you use).

> What's the benefit of storing state in ViewModel (from Android Architecture Components) rather the Application class or a Singleton?

A `ViewModel`, retained fragments, and `onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance()` are for holding state unique to a running activity, across configuration changes for that activity. At most — if you screw something up — they temporarily cause a memory leak, but that will get cleared up as soon as the overall activity is destroyed. Also, because these are scoped to an individual activity, you can easily have N of them for N logical activity instances, which may or may not be practical with process-wide solutions.

In general, in computer programming, we aim to keep our data in the narrowest scope possible (["information hiding"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding)). Using things that are global in scope runs counter to that design principle. Hence, using singletons is *possible*, but should be reserved for cases where it is unavoidable or vastly superior to using a narrower scope. In Android, we use singletons far more than you would in ordinary Java development, where singletons are [often considered to be evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons).